# UseEffect runs while it should wait for await in other function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await, use-effect

I'm having a problem with useEffect and async-await function and I'm not sure how to explain. Let me try: I have two components, parent and child, and the parent sends some props to the child, including a funtion to modify some state and the state. The child use this props in useEffect hook to generate new states and use the funtion inside a async-await function to modify the states back in the parent. The child uses this function inside a for loop inside an async function, however, useEffect keeps runing and doesn't allow me to modify all states in the parent. This is a very simplified code, I hope is enough:

function in parent

```
const createEntry = async(entry) => {
        const dummyEntries = clone(entries);
        console.log('Entradas:');
        console.log(dummyEntries);
        dummyEntries.push(entry);    
        setEntries(dummyEntries)    
        return json.id;
    }
```

It sends entries and createEntry to child

functions in child

```
useEffect(()=>{
//create some states, called entries, with props.entries
},[props.entries])

const Save = async () => {
    if (Object.values(error).some((e) => e.value === true)) {
      setModal(true);
    } else if (props.accion === 'crear') {
      for (const item of entries){
        await props.createEntry(item) 
      }
      history.push(`/path/`);
    } else if (props.accion === 'editar') {
      for (const item of entries){
        if (!item.id) {
          console.log(item)
          await props.createEntry(item)
        }
      }
      history.push(`/path`);
    }
  };
```

Only the last term in entries of Child component is saved in entries of Parent component

Comment: Calling `props.createEntry` *once* will call `setEntries`, which will make the useEffect function run again since `props.entries` has changed.

Comment: only the last item is saved because the parent and the child component have a closure over the state which was in-effect when `useEffect` hook was executed. I suggest you first make an object that you want to save in the state and then _after_ the loop, call the state setter function.

Comment: In the child I should send the object with all entries to the parent and I save it all together in the parent?

Comment: Yes. Don't call the state setter function passed from parent inside a loop in the child component.

Comment: Perfect! It's working now :) So, for future coding, the useEffect doesn't care about the async-await, right?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, thank you to the commenters! This is the working code:

function in parent

```
const createEntry = async(new_entries) => {
   const dummyEntries = clone(new_entries);
   for (const entry of new_entries){
            dummyEntries=[...dummyEntries,json]
    }  

    setEntries(dummyEntries)   
    }
```

functions in child

```
useEffect(()=>{
//create some states, called entries, with props.entries
},[props.entries])

const Save = async () => {
    if (Object.values(error).some((e) => e.value === true)) {
      setModal(true);
    } else if (props.accion === 'crear') {
      await props.createEntry(entries) 
      history.push(`/path/`);
    } else if (props.accion === 'editar') {
      await props.createEntry(entries)
      history.push(`/path`);
    }
  };
```

I use the async-await because there are some fetchs in the middle.